# WCF username and password without SSL and Custom Authentication Class

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, basic-authentication

i'm new with WCF and security in general.
I'm trying to implement a basic authentication in WCF without using SSL and using a custom class (by inheriting the class UserNamePasswordValidator) for validating username and password. I don't want to use a certificate, in fact, for what i need, i just need to send username and pasword without any encryption.

When i tried to configure my WCF service (based on this [link](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2006/07/31/890.aspx" link")), by setting the security mode of the credential type as "TransportCredentialOnly" and the binding type as "basicHttpBinding", after trying to consume this service in a console application test, the authentication doesn't work (actually, i put a breakpoint in the authentication class and it is never stops there).

This is how my Web.Config looks like

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BeneficiarioServiceBasicBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour.BeneficiarioService" >
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication  userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                                 customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WCF.Configuration.ServicoAutenticacao, ProgramasSociais.WCF" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

---

Authentication Class (just a test class)

```
public class ServicoAutenticacao : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (userName != "Test" && password != "Test")
        {
            throw new FaultException("Invalid user and/or password");
        }
    }
}
```

I found some similar problems here in stack overflow, however, i did not find any solution that fix my problem.

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe this helps you, this is a Solution with `httpTransportCredentialOnlyBinding` and  `TransportCredentialOnly` http://stackoverflow.com/a/28098417/1776231