# Unable to do basic authentification with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to create a web service WCF with a basic authentification, followinf [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-basic-authentication).

But when I want to test it by adding service reference in my C# application, I have an error (In french sorry) :

> System.NotSupportedException: Les schémas d'authentification
>   configurés sur l'hôte ('Anonymous') n'autorisent pas ceux configurés
>   sur la liaison 'BasicHttpBinding' ('Basic'). Assurez-vous que la
>   valeur de SecurityMode est Transport ou TransportCredentialOnly. En
>   outre, ceci peut être résolu en modifiant les schémas
>   d'authentification de cette application par le biais de l'outil de
>   gestion IIS, la propriété
>   ServiceHost.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemes, dans le fichier de
>   configuration de l'application, au niveau de l'élément
>   , en mettant à jour la propriété
>   ClientCredentialType de la liaison ou en ajustant la propriété
>   AuthenticationScheme de l'élément HttpTransportBindingElement.

It says something like there is trouble between schemes 'Anonymous' and 'Basic'. But I don't know what it is.

There is my code :

```
namespace WcfWebHttpIISHostingSample
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface ITestService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(string data);
    }
    public class ServiceTest : ITestService
    {
        public string GetData(string data)
        {
            return "OK";
        }
    }
}
```

Web.config :

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="UsernameWithTransportCredentialOnly">
        <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ServiceWithMetaData">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>

  <services>
    <service name="WcfWebHttpIISHostingSample.ServiceTest" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceWithMetaData">
      <endpoint
        address="http://localhost:17625/ServiceTest.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="UsernameWithTransportCredentialOnly"
        name="BasicEndpoint"
        contract="WcfWebHttpIISHostingSample.ITestService">
      </endpoint>
    </service>
  </services>

  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

I've try to change some details in config but I still have the error.

==================================================================

I also saw [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093260/turn-on-basic-authentication-for-a-simple-wcf-service) with the same problem but the solution provided doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because I changed the Authentification type after creating my project, the solution was to modify the file in `MyProject\.vs\config\applicationhost.config`

In this file, set anonymousAuthentication to `false` and basicAuthentication to `true`:

```
<security>

    <access sslFlags="None" />

    <applicationDependencies>
        <application name="Active Server Pages" groupId="ASP" />
    </applicationDependencies>

    <authentication>
        <!-- this line was set to "true" -->
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" userName="" />

        <!-- this line was set to "false" -->
        <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />

<!-- etc ... -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a clash between the Authentication types supported by your WCF service in IIS, i.e. Anonymous, and your WCF config which is using Basic.

Either enable 'Basic' under Authentication for the WCF service in IIS or remove the `<security>` element from your config file.

I'm not sure which is appropriate for you.

Comment: I have disabled the `Anonymous Authentification` in IIS manager and Enabled the `Basic Authentification` but error is still there.